# AWS SSM : Ordering SSM Document association with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

I want to install the CloudWatch Agent on EC2 instances and then configure it. I've created two different SSM associations with AWS documents but when I execute the Terraform script, they both get executed at the same time.

How could I order the execution of these document ?

```
###install cloudwatch agent 
resource "aws_ssm_association" "ssm-cloudwatchagent" {
  name = "AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage"
  parameters = {
  action = "Install"
  name = "AmazonCloudWatchAgent"
  }
  targets {
    key    = "InstanceIds"
    values = ["*"]
  }
}

### configure agent 
resource "aws_ssm_association" "ssm-cloudwatchagent-config" {
  name = "AmazonCloudWatch-ManageAgent"
  parameters = {
  action = "configure"
  mode = "ec2"
  optionalRestart = "yes"
  optionalConfigurationSource = "ssm"
  optionalConfigurationLocation = aws_ssm_parameter.AmazonCloudWatch-config.name ## confg stored in parameter store
  }
  targets {
    key    = "InstanceIds"
    values = ["*"]
  }
  depends_on = [
    aws_ssm_association.ssm-cloudwatchagent
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide TF code demonstrating your issue.

Comment: If AWS is executing them simultaneously despite the gap in the operations by the TF AWS provider, then you probably need to additionally add some kind of delay between the two.

Answer (score 0):

For the `ssm-cloudwatchagent-config`resource, did you try to play with the following arguments `apply_only_at_cron_interval` and `schedule_expression` ?

Could you also share the error you're getting?